# What does 'glassed-off' mean here?

Tags: phrase-meaning

> “Well then,” he said, running a hand through his hair and cutting his
>   eyes anxiously towards the door. “I’ll leave you now. Hell of a thing
>   that’s happened, good Lord. You must be feeling awfully rough. A good
>   solid sleep will be the best thing in the world for you. Are you
>   tired?” he said, looking at me closely. Was I? I was wide awake, and
>   yet part of me was so **glassed-off** and numb I was practically in a
>   coma.

*The Goldfinch* by Donna Tartt

What does **glassed-off** mean here? Is it along the line of 'detached, sequestered?

Comment: As if behind a thick glass window, as we find in bullet-proof kiosks where a person inside takes money and needs to be protected. **off** is the clue.  Walled off (by thick glass).  Isolated.  A barrier between oneself and the world.  You are on the right track with "detached, sequestered".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's a metaphor meaning *as if covered with glass*, i.e. your word **sequestered** is correct.